# Expressing action of taking off

Tags: kanji, definitions, kanji-choice

Like saying I'm going to take off my hat as in 帽子{ぼうし}を抜{ぬ}きます. I believe 抜{ぬ} "nu" means to get ride of or dispose of, but I guess I'm certain context it could mean to take off or remove. I'm wondering if there's a kanji that better fits this action.

Comment: 「抜く」 means "to pull out".  You would never say 「帽子を抜く」 unless you had a hat stuck somewhere and had to yank it out.

Comment: ぬ is "nu" by the way, not "ne," which is ね

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to say *Take off one's hat* is 帽子【ぼうし】を脱【ぬ】ぐ.
It is the same ぬぐ as in 服【ふく】を脱【ぬ】ぐ (Take off one's clothes).

You can find the expression [脱帽【だつぼう】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%84%B1%E5%B8%BD-561446)  which uses the same kanji and means "taking one's hat off to someone".

Comment: 「脱帽」 actually means something else.

Comment: @l'électeur what does「脱帽」mean?

Comment: It specifically  means "taking one's hat off to someone to show him respect".  It is not the word you asked for.

Comment: @l'électeur Yeah that's what written in the definition I linked, I know you can't use it to just say "I take off my hat" in any context. I just wanted to emphasize the fact that it uses the same kanjis. Besides, we have the same expression "take one's hat off to someone" in English (and in French, my native language too) with a very similar meaning of showing someone your respect/giving them praise.

Comment: @Cendolt  The idiom exists in Spanish and Catalan, too